# Including concatenated scripts asynchronously with gulp.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, gulp

I'm trying to do the following:

```
gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('_temp.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));

gulp.src('build/js/app.js')
    .pipe(replace('// includes', fs.readFileSync('js/_temp.js')))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
```

So, I'm concatenating all `.js` files in `js/`. The concatenated file is named `_temp.js`;

After that, I'm reading a `app.js` and try to replace the `// includes` string with the concatenated `_temp.js` file. This doesn't work as node says the file doesn't exist. It does exist though, so I second time I run this task, it works.

**This has most probably to do with asynchronisity, but I'm unable to see how I would do this differently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your task into 2 and make one of the tasks run after another by using Gulp's dependency resolution system.

```
gulp.task('task1', function () { ... });
gulp.task('task2', ['task1'], function () { ... });
```

Comment: You may also want to look at gulpfile.js in this project: https://github.com/kriasoft/spa-seed.front-end